# Alternative to Keynote with better typography options?

Tags: software-recommendation, keynote

What software are people using on a Mac to create nice-looking presentation slides, notably, with custom drop shadows on text?

Comment: The question as stated is extremely broad. Any constraints, e.g. concerning price, ease of learning etc.? Are custom drop shadows your only requirement which is not covered by Keynote or are there others (as the title says)?

Comment: @patrix It is my main requirement right now – I was feeling a question title mentioning this only requirement would be too localized?

Comment: I see your point. As stated now the question runs the risk of getting closed of being not constructive enough. At least adding some pricing brackets would help (Adobe surely has something for you here but is quite expensive).

Comment: It would also be helpful if you specified what you mean by "custom drop shadows". Keynote already lets you adjust the color, angle, distance, blur, and opacity of drop shadows; what are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: @jmk I just found that out, so my question is void... Should I close/delete it?